# Printing array as sub blocks

Tags: arrays, c, nested-loops

I have array and I am trying to print this array as sub blocks, where each block has size = 5.
the out put of this code not as I expected it just print the first 5 values. How  to print the array as sub blocks?

```
int arr[298] = {some int values};
int in = 0;
int siz = 298;
int ii;
int rang = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
    if (in <= siz) {
        for (ii = in; ii < 5; ii++) {
            printf("arr=%d \n", arr[ii]);
        }
        printf("------------\n");
    }
    ind = ind + rang;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your request for clarification in the comment section, there are a few problems with your code, for me the biggest one is that it's needlessly complicated, but the one you are looking for is in this line:

```
ind = ind + rang;
```

`ind` is is not declared in your code but I assume you mean `in`, the first time the inner loop runs `in`(`ind`) is 0 so it all goes well, after that `in` will be 5, you assign it to `ii` and the condition `ii < 5` will never be true again, the body of the loop will never be executed.

I suppose you could fix it by using `in` as index for the array and scrap `rang` since it isn't needed, something like this:

```
int arr[298] = {some int values};
int in = 0;
int siz = 298;

for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
    //if (in < siz) { moving this into the for loop
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 5 && in < siz; ii++, in++) {
            printf("arr=%d \n", arr[in]);
        }
        printf("------------\n");
    //}
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/YzG9sno1n

But you don't need a nested loop, there are a few ways you can do this, a simple one is to have a variable that controls the block size:

```
int arr[298] = {some int values};
int siz = 298;   
int count = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
    
        printf("arr=%d \n", arr[i]);
        count--;
    
    if (count == 0) {
        printf("------------\n");
        count = 5;
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/b4e8vWfhM

In the above code `count` serves as the control variable, the value in the index is printed 5 times and when it reaches 0 a separator is printed and it resets and starts the new block.

Another possible option is to use the index itself to separate the blocks, you know the remainder of a division is 0 when the numerator is divisible by the denominator, you can use that to your advantage:

```
int arr[298] = {some int values};

int siz = 298;

for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) { // && i != 0 if you want to skip the initial separator
        printf("------------\n");
    }
    printf("arr=%d \n", arr[i]);       
}
```

Live demo : https://godbolt.org/z/nne3z38rY

Finally you can/should use a constant value for size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 298

int main() {

    int arr[SIZE] = {some int values};

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0  && i != 0) { // skipping the initial separator
            printf("------------\n");
        }
        printf("arr=%d \n", arr[i]);       
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Mc4Yh4cav

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but what is the issue in my code?

Comment: @kayla I added an explanation to the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of several for loops, you can use a single while loop.

```
int arr[298 ]={Some int Values};
int ind =0;
int siz= 298 ; 
printf("------------\n");   
while(ind<=siz-1){
    printf("arr=%d \n",arr[ind]);  
    ind++;
    if(ind%5==0){
    printf("------------\n");   
    }
}
```

In this, you print the elements through 0 to 297, with a line of dashes printed if the index is divisible by 5, that is after every fifth element.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but what is the issue in my code?